# How do i retrieve an ecr image with terraform and set a default value if it not exists?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to obtain the latest image and use another tag that the latest image has. This is because EC2 tends to cache the image if you reference it directly with the tag "latest," so the next time the service is up, you may be running an older image. Therefore, we tag the image twice: first with "latest" and then with a hash.

This approach works perfectly when there are already images in the ECR. However, if there aren't any images, Terraform throws an error.

```
data "aws_ecr_image" "image"{
  repository_name = module.ecr.repository_name
  image_tag       = try("latest", "")

  depends_on = [
    module.ecr #this is my ecr repository module
  ]
}

module "container_definition" {
  source                       = "cloudposse/ecs-container-definition/aws"
  version                      = "0.58.1"
  container_name               = local.container_name
  container_image              = "${module.global_settings.aws_account_id}.dkr.ecr.${module.global_settings.region}.amazonaws.com/${local.project_name}:${try(data.aws_ecr_image.image.image_tags[1], "latest")}"
  
  container_memory             = local.memory
  container_memory_reservation = local.memory_reservarion
  container_cpu                = local.cpu
  essential                    = local.essential
  readonly_root_filesystem     = local.readonly_root_system
  environment                  = local.task_environment_variables
  secrets                      = local.task_environment_secret_variables
  port_mappings                = local.port_mappings
  log_configuration            = local.container_log_configuration

  depends_on = [
    module.ecr
  ]
}
```

i just want to hardcode "latest" if there arent any images. The service cant start because that image doesnt exist but the pipeline is gonna be executed right after that. Im trying to avoid the creation of a dummy image just for this pourpose

any ideas?

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have now?

Comment: It throws an error when the image doesnt exist. Error: reading ECR Images: ImageNotFoundException: The image with imageId {imageDigest:'null', imageTag:'latest'} does not exist within the repository with name 'test123' in the registry with id '123456789'. And i know it doesnt exist xD i just want to set a default value in this case

Comment: In the future, when I want to update environment variables, It will retrieve the latest image generated by the pipeline and reference it using the hash tag. This way, I guarantee that It will always use the latest image without any caching problems

Comment: Hey - I came across this post as I've just ran into the same problem.

My solution is to use coalesce with a command line provided variable or `latest`

The idea is that one will be present in our case.

If you want to say not have to have something in there, perhaps you need to break up your TF into separate configs and only run the one that relies on images when there is one.

Comment: @BenS Hi Ben! i ended up creating a dummy image. I created a "dummy" ecr repository and in this module before asking for the latest image, i pull and push the dummy image from its repository to the current repository with latest tag